# Выполнение JS кода на стороннем сайте

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, интернет-магазин

Столкнулся со следующим вопросом.  Есть интернет-магазин. Процесс оплаты банковской картой происходит посредством нажатия кнопки "Оплатить". Данная кнопка осуществляет переход на страницу банка , где уже необходимо вводить данные карты для оплаты товара.
Кнопка "Оплатить" реализована следующим образом:

```
<form action="<?php echo $paySystemParams["START_PAYMENT_URL"]; ?>" method="GET" name="payment_form">

// Тут передаются параметры заказа типа order_id и прочее

// Сама кнопка оплаты
<div style="padding: 20px 0">
            <input type="submit" value="Оплатить" class="" name="sbmt">
        </div>
</form>
```

Все это лирика.  На стороне банка есть шаблоны для разных способов оплаты, которые при этом имеют один и тот же url :

```
<div id="sposob1" style="display: block;">
        
 </div>

<div id="sposob2" style="display: none;">
        
 </div>
```

По умолчанию видимым является блок с id sposob1 .  Также есть кнопка без id, назовем ее SBT,  которая делает видимым блок с id sposob2 и скрывает базовый блок + эта кнопка запускает один скрипт по формированию qr-кода ( это настройка системы быстрых платежей ) .  Вопрос собственно заключается в том , можно ли при отправке данных по кнопке "Оплатить" дополнительно еще отправить событие по нажатию кнопки SBT , чтобы для пользователя видимым становился блок со вторым способом ? Ручным вводом в консоли естественно все окей, а вот реально ли это сделать автоматически ? Напрямую ковырять классы на стороне страницы банка также не получится , т.к кнопка SBT запускает скрипт по формированию qr кода .  Надеюсь понятно смог донести суть своего вопроса.

Comment: Спросите у банка.

Comment: Ну вы же сами пишете, что все это находится на стороне банка, а значит вы к этому вряд ли будете иметь доступ. Если это непосредственно сайт банка -- сто процентов не получите. Если на вашем сайте через `iframe` -- та же история. Вам лучше написать в ТП платежной системы и поинтересоваться, можно ли поменять способ оплаты по умолчанию при передаче GET-параметров

Comment: Выполнение скриптов на чужой странице попросту запрещено, это вопрос безопасности. Максимум, что возможно - выполнить скрипт из одной своей странице на другой своей в ифрейме, при целой куче условий (одинаковый базовый урл, известное имя фрейма и т.п.). 

Ваш вариант - дрючить техподдержку банка и читать доку по его API.

Comment: В принципе так и думал ,  всем спасибо за ответ .

Comment: читайте доки по поводу подключения формы, возможно, там с параметрами можно указать активный способ оплаты. На крайний случай напишите в суппорт, где нить в доках вероятно должны быть контакты